# How to suppress Mavens INFO spam without suppressing normal output?

Tags: maven

I would like to use Mavens `dependency:build-classpath` to create a class path:

```
$ mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.prefix='lib' -f xpath.pom
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xpath 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:build-classpath (default-cli) @ xpath ---
[INFO] Dependencies classpath:
lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar:lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar:lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.251s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 26 16:37:01 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I stop Mavens INFO spam without suppressing the intended output of `build-classpath`?

I found answers, which explain that I have to use the `-q` option to suppress INFO output. But using this option results in no output at all.

I know I can use `grep`, but I would like to avoid it. And I can not believe that Maven can not do this out of the box, because it makes the dependency plugin quite useless.

This is the complete pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>nobody</groupId>
  <artifactId>xpath</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xalan</groupId>
      <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is not ideal for some, but you can use [outputFile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html#outputFile) to have it put the output into a file.

Answer (score -2):

`INFO` is the very minimal amount of information you ***really*** need to be seeing about the build. This is the default logging level it's using. If you tell it not to use `INFO`, then all the log messages in Maven and the plugins you're using will simply not output anything.

Comment: Mavens fault is, that there is no separation between logging and output. For functions like build-classpath a way to output something is necessary. It is about 40 years ago since somebody invents stdout. Mavens silliness is to forget it. And by the way: I can not imagine any reason why I _really_ need to see this line `[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------` six times.

Comment: The problem is that the logging should have a few more levels. However, even if it did, most developers aren't used to using fine-grained logging. In the end, you end up with all this information which is printed out and most of it is at a level between info and debug, if you ask me.

Comment: To output something is not a proper subset of to log something. This operations are distinct from each other.

Comment: please also keep in mind that Maven is not _ju st_ a build tool, there are lots of plugins and people who use them. I'm here because I'm using test plugins with eclim. It's kind of nice, or it would be if my eyes didn't constantly didn't have to parse out a ton of useless verbiage.

And I think this verbiage is a problem: the more I encounter it, the more I tend to skim, the more I skim, the less attentive I become, and make mistakes that cost me real time.

Answer (score -2):

In linux you can add a grep -v INFO to the end of your statement

`$ mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.parent.version |grep -v INFO
4.0.6-a
$`

Comment: Yes but the idea of Maven is to be platform independent. If I want to relay on `grep` I can also write an Makefile.